# openpyxl 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'(python)

Tags: python, excel, parsing, openxls

Sorry for my English. I need to open a xlsx document and write in the last position new values. But I don't understand how to do it. My algorithm works  like this:

1. Open xlsx `l_workbook = load_workbook(old_log_tmp_path)`
2. Get all value from there

   Code:

   ```
   def iter_rows(ws):
       for row in ws.iter_rows():
           yield [cell for cell in row]
   ```
3. Create new xlsm file

   Code:

   ```
   workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(tf.name)
   worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
   ```
4. Copy all values from `l_workbook` to `workbook -> worksheet`

---

But I think it is not right, I think they exist in a simple way. Like this:

```
 l_workbook = load_workbook('EX2cRqM7xi1D.xlsx')
 sheet = l_workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
 worksheet = l_workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
 worksheet.write(1, 1, "TEST")
```

Running that script gave me the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**My question is:** How can I open xlsm file and add new values to it (using openpyxl)?

**UPD:**

i try this code, but not work

```
import openpyxl

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('tmp3by148hj.xlsx')
    ws = workbook.worksheets[0]

    ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'TEST'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write into a cell:

```
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'TEST'
```

and finally save your changes:

```
workbook.save('tmp3by148hj.xlsx')
```

Comment: thks for answer, but i try and it not work. I update my qestion